# Changing the font family for all styles in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, fonts, styles

Excel has styles like "Normal", "Bad", "Good", "Calculation" etc.

[image]

You can change the font family for each style by right-clicking on it and choosing Modify → Format → Font. However, there are about 17 styles in the default template, so changing them one by one takes some time.

How can I change the font family (Calibri → Times New Roman) for all / multiple styles at once?

(The question was asked also [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/fi-fi/msoffice/forum/all/changing-the-font-family-for-all-styles-in-excel/790faefd-c2a6-4eae-a633-a2bb91f0db9e).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options → General → When creating new worksbooks → Use this as the default font: [choose ▾]

The chosen font family will be used for all the styles mentioned in the question.

(I copied the idea from [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/fi-fi/msoffice/forum/all/changing-the-font-family-for-all-styles-in-excel/790faefd-c2a6-4eae-a633-a2bb91f0db9e?tab=AllReplies#allReplies).)